# Application Secrets for a .Net Framework application

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, csom

I have a Net Framework application that uses the CSOM library to interact with SharePoint. How can I securely store the SharePoint credentials used by the library?

I have tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=windows) guide, but the library is incompatible because it is written for Net Core while CSOM is on Net Framework.

I have reviewed the [CSOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) documentation, but it does not have a best practice for storing the application credentials.

This application is a integration point between SharePoint Online and another cloud application that we support, so I have not configured a database because the transactions simply pass through the app without needing to store anything. Also I am considering using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to host the application, so would that give me any additional options to store the credentials?

Comment: Are you using asp.net ?

Comment: And if you are using AWS why dont u use AWS secret mamager?

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1, Also I am looking into https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/ Since Csom only runs on net framework will I run into issues?

Comment: I looked into this approach https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/kms-keys-s3-encryption.html, but I could not one of the lines to resolve properly

Comment: You will have your AMI : Windows Server Core 2016 with IIS 10.0 version 1.2.0

64bit Windows Server Core 2016 v1.2.0 running IIS 10.0

.NET Core 2.0, supports 2.0.x, 1.1.x, 1.0.x

.NET Framework 4.7, supports 4.x, 2.0, 1.x

Comment: Why you dont want to store it encryptes in ur web.config

Comment: So are you saying in AWS the first guide will work? I couldnt get it to build locally due to a .Core dependency, but on AWS it will have that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171788/discussion-between-hany-habib-and-jeff).

Comment: I am looking into that now, this may be the way to go, I think I got side tracked in my research because I was too focused on the specifics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to complete that :

1) use normally the web.config and encrypt your keys for ex using aspnet_regiis

Full tutorial :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dtkwfdky.aspx

2) If you are using AWS u can use the Secret Manager.